# bootstrap column image mis alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to display 3 images per row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="" /></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="" /></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When it is displayed the images seem to be misaligned as in the picture. I would like them all to start at the bottom
Could anyone let me know how to fix it.
Thank you.
http://invent-o.org/lb/stack1.PNG

Comment: Since Bootstrap columns are set to `relative` position, you could use absolute positioning for your images, like: `.col-md-4 > img { position: absolute; bottom: 0 }`.

Comment: Thank you but that does not work.

Comment: Without seeing what you've already tried. Here's a working demo using the absolute bottom position on the image. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBjRyw

Comment: It works now. Thank you. How should I accept a comment as an answer?

Comment: Excellent! No worries. Glad to just help. :)